# Why the element id doesn't getting when using event.target?

Tags: angular, typescript, runtime-error

I'm trying to get the element id when I click on the button, but sometimes this id doesn't getting.
code below, I'm using typescript!

image below!

```
          <div *ngFor="let item of l">
              <input type="text" class="form-control">
              <button (click)="getRate($event)"><i class="far fa-star" id='1'></i></button>
              <button (click)="getRate($event)"><i class="far fa-star" id='2'></i></button>
              <button (click)="getRate($event)"><i class="far fa-star" id='3'></i></button>
              <button (click)="getRate($event)"><i class="far fa-star" id='4'></i></button>
              <button (click)="getRate($event)"><i class="far fa-star" id='5'></i></button>
          </div>
```

Typescript method to calculate rate besed on star id.

```
  getRate(event: Event) {
    this.ratesArray.push((((event.target as Element).id as unknown) as number) * 20);
    console.log((event.target as Element).id);
    console.log((((event.target as Element).id as unknown) as number));
  }
```

[image]

Comment: not sure but I think you should give IDs to button not on `i`

Comment: the id is not on your button element. So you have to switch it or you select the i-element -> `event.target.querySelector('.far').id`

Comment: Also, doesn't work, is there any other ways to get the id, or calculate the rate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, the idea is that when I click on the button, it will return null, because I'm getting the  id.

```
getRate(event: Event) {
    //this.ratesArray.push((((event.target as Element).id as unknown) as number) * 20);
    if ((event.target as Element).id == null) {
      console.log((event.target as Element).closest("a").id);
    } else {
      console.log((event.target as Element).id);
    }
    console.log((((event.target as Element).id as unknown) as number));
  }
```

```
    <a (click)="getRate($event)" id="1"><i class="far fa-star" id="1"></i></a>
    <a (click)="getRate($event)" id="2"><i class="far fa-star" id="2"></i></a>
    <a (click)="getRate($event)" id="3"><i class="far fa-star" id="3"></i></a>
    <a (click)="getRate($event)" id="4"><i class="far fa-star" id="4"></i></a>
    <a (click)="getRate($event)" id="5"><i class="far fa-star" id="5"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is little bit tricky. one thing is you have `i` tag inside the button element.if you click on `i` tag it will give the id, otherwise not.
in html use `id` in the button tag

```
<button (click)="getRate($event)" id='1'><i class="far fa-star" ></i></button>
```

and from the component

```
 getRate(event: Event) {
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement || event.currentTarget;
    var id = target.attributes.id;

  }
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I tried but it still present some of the id's and some of them no.